# Automatically entering next JSON level using Python in a similar way to JQ in bash

Tags: python, json

I am trying to use Python to extract pricePerUnit from JSON.  There are many entries, and this is just 2 of them -

```
{
  "terms": {
    "OnDemand": {
      "7Y9ZZ3FXWPC86CZY": {
        "7Y9ZZ3FXWPC86CZY.JRTCKXETXF": {
          "offerTermCode": "JRTCKXETXF",
          "sku": "7Y9ZZ3FXWPC86CZY",
          "effectiveDate": "2020-11-01T00:00:00Z",
          "priceDimensions": {
            "7Y9ZZ3FXWPC86CZY.JRTCKXETXF.6YS6EN2CT7": {
              "rateCode": "7Y9ZZ3FXWPC86CZY.JRTCKXETXF.6YS6EN2CT7",
              "description": "Processed translation request in AWS GovCloud (US)",
              "beginRange": "0",
              "endRange": "Inf",
              "unit": "Character",
              "pricePerUnit": {
                "USD": "0.0000150000"
              },
              "appliesTo": []
            }
          },
          "termAttributes": {}
        }
      },
      "CQNY8UFVUNQQYYV4": {
        "CQNY8UFVUNQQYYV4.JRTCKXETXF": {
          "offerTermCode": "JRTCKXETXF",
          "sku": "CQNY8UFVUNQQYYV4",
          "effectiveDate": "2020-11-01T00:00:00Z",
          "priceDimensions": {
            "CQNY8UFVUNQQYYV4.JRTCKXETXF.6YS6EN2CT7": {
              "rateCode": "CQNY8UFVUNQQYYV4.JRTCKXETXF.6YS6EN2CT7",
              "description": "$0.000015 per Character for TextTranslationJob:TextTranslationJob in EU (London)",
              "beginRange": "0",
              "endRange": "Inf",
              "unit": "Character",
              "pricePerUnit": {
                "USD": "0.0000150000"
              },
              "appliesTo": []
            }
          },
          "termAttributes": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The issue I run into is that the keys, which in this sample, are `7Y9ZZ3FXWPC86CZY`, `CQNY8UFVUNQQYYV4.JRTCKXETXF`, and `CQNY8UFVUNQQYYV4.JRTCKXETXF.6YS6EN2CT7` are a changing string that I cannot just type out as I am parsing the dictionary.

I have python code that works for the first level of these random keys -

```
with open('index.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

json_keys=list(data['terms']['OnDemand'].keys())

#Get the region
for i in json_keys:
    print((data['terms']['OnDemand'][i]))
```

However, this is tedious, as I would need to run the same code three times to get the other keys like `7Y9ZZ3FXWPC86CZY.JRTCKXETXF` and `7Y9ZZ3FXWPC86CZY.JRTCKXETXF.6YS6EN2CT7`, since the string changes with each JSON entry.

Is there a way that I can just tell python to automatically enter the next level of the JSON object, without having to parse all keys, save them, and then iterate through them?  Using JQ in bash I can do this quite easily with `jq -r '.terms[][][]'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are really sure, that there is exactly one key-value pair on each level, you can try the following:

```
def descend(x, depth):
    for i in range(depth):
        x = next(iter(x.values()))

    return x
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dict.values()` to iterate over the values of a dict. You can also use `next(iter(dict.values()))` to get a first (only) element of a dict.

```
for demand in data['terms']['OnDemand'].values():
    next_level = next(iter(demand.values()))
    print(next_level)
```

If you expect other number of children than 1 in the second level, you can just nest the fors:

```
for demand in data['terms']['OnDemand'].values():
    for sub_demand in demand.values()
        print(sub_demand)
```

If you are insterested in the keys too, you can use `dict.items()` method to iterate over dict keys and values at the same time:

```
for demand_key, demand in data['terms']['OnDemand'].items():
    for sub_demand_key, sub_demand in demand.items()
        print(demand_key, sub_demand_key, sub_demand)
```